# How to get all contracts that were accessed in a transaction?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, ethers.js, etherscan

I see that according to [ether docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionReceipt, I can see the contract address of the first called contract. However, I am interested in seeing if a certain set of contracts was interacted with in a transaction.

I can look  this up on [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x79b5377d18b94c2975dee1fa60877bfcdbb6f09dc24b392bf23c1961b1b5048a/advanced#internal), but how can I do this computationally? I know I can look up each of the ~200 txn in each new block on etherscan, but this seems really inefficient and will violate their API limit.

Answer (score 0):

The list of internal transactions on Etherscan is built from debug of the main transaction.

For example the Go Ethereum node client software contains a non-standardized RPC method [debug_traceTransaction](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interacting-with-geth/rpc/ns-debug#debugtracetransaction) that returns the list of all opcodes executed during the transaction.

The list of all valid opcodes for Ethereum can be found on the Ethereum webstite: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/opcodes/.

And the opcodes that are reflected on Etherscan representing rows in the table of "Internal transactions" are `CALL`, `STATICCALL` and `DELEGATECALL`. Each of them accepts a few parameters - and one of them is the target address.

Comment: Are there any RPC providers that support this? Otherwise, I would have to run my own full ETH node, right?

Comment: Yes, most providers enable debug in their paid plans. Or you can also run your own node and enable the debug on the node.